# Adding an element to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to generate an array with 60 elements. The element[0] will be obtained from input. The element[1] has to be element[0]*2 and so on. this means element[2] has to be element[1]*2.
Please let me know how can generate this array in js.

**example:**
input value=100
output array=[100,200,400,800,.......]

Thanks

Comment: Read the lecture notes to do your homework

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**  method

```js
var value = 100;

var arr = new Array(60) // generate an array of size 60
  .fill(value) // fill it with form value
  .map(function(v, i) { // genearte updated array
    return v * (i + 1); // do the arithematic operations
  });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code:

Assume you have one input text as below:

```
<input type='text' id='input' />
```

and one button as below:

```
<button type='button' onclick='getArray();'>Generate Array</button>
```

and below function in javascript

```
<script>
function getArray()
{
   var element = [];
   var val = parseInt($('#input').val());

   var j = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
   {
       if (i == 0)
       {
           element[i] = val;
       }
       else
       {
           element[i] = element[j] * 2;
           j++;
       }
   }

   alert(element);
}
</script>
```

I'm sure this will help you and if it does then don't forget to mark my answer... ;)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = 100;
var length = 60;

var array = new Array(length);
array[0] = input;

for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i - 1] * 2;
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for creating the expected array. Its second argument is an equivalent of the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
let getArr = input => Array.from({length: 60}, (value, index) => Math.pow(2,index) * input);
```